# Insert Group And Content in OpenAceess

Tags: linq, entity-framework, openaccess, telerik-open-access

I have a many to many relation beetween Group  and Content table in sql and i imperilment this with a junction table .it name is  GroupContent .

when i try to insert a new Group  and Content the Openaccess insert a Group and a Content and Dose not insert any record to my junction table.
this is my code

```
using (Context orm = new Context ())
        {
            Group objGroup = new Group();
            objGroup.GroupName = "group 1";

            Content objContent = new Content();
            objContent.ContentDetail = "content 1";

            objGroup.Contents.Add(objContent );
            orm.Add(objGroup );
            orm.Add(objContent);

            orm.SaveChanges();


        }
```

Can i Use this to code with Entity Framework.

Comment: First - 'orm.Add(Content)' is probably a typo. Have you set-up the m:n association correctly in the designer? If this is a database-first approach, have you mapped the join table correctly in the designer?

Comment: i use database-first approach and i mapped correctly in sql server.when i use open access wizard to create model it dosen't crate my join table in model and it only show many to many relation between Group and Content.

Comment: If OpenAccess creates the other tables but not the join table there seems to be some ambiguity in the mapping. You could open a support ticket with Telerik and send your rlinq file over. Your problem would be solved faster that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default collection properties are not managed (persisted) in OpenAccess.

You need to mark the navigation member with IsManaged. Just open the designer, find the navigation property (in this case the Contents property of the Group class) and trough the Properties Pane, change the IsManaged to true.